# Writing the list of first n natural numbers as ints in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I need a list describing a range such as in:

```
[0..<length P]
```

However this has type `nat list`. I later need its type to be `int list`.

How can I do such a conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably `map int [0..<length p]`. In fact, if you just write down `[0..<length p]` Isabelle might well insert that as a coercion automatically.

It is a bit unfortunate that this notation only exists for `nat`; I suppose it is simply not used very often. The equivalent notation for sets (`{a..<b}` etc.) is much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `List.upto` with special syntax `[m..n]` to generate a list of integers (type `int list`) from `m` *upto* `n` (where both lower and upper bound are inclusive).

So in your case I would probably use

```
[0 .. int (length xs) - 1]
```

(Note that you still need a conversion from `nat` to `int` for the result of `length`.